# Run-time error '52': Bad file name or number (SharePoint link vs Windows path)

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to assign a SharePoint link to flnameI I get a "Run-time error '52':  Bad file name or number" on the yellow highlighte line in the image I attached
e.g. when flnameI = **https://cogsandwheels.sharepoint.com/sites/accountsdept/test.xlsx**

But when flnameI is equal to a windows explorer path like **C:\Users\John.test.xlsx** I get no issues.

How do I cater for a SharePoint link in this example?

```
flnameI = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + folder + "\" + txtAgentFile.value

If Len(Dir(flnameI)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("FATAL ERROR - file not found - " + flnameI)
    End
End If
```

[image]

Comment: You can't use `Dir()` on a HTTP[S] path - it just doesn't work.  I'm not aware of any reliable and straightforward alternate method which works with SharePoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to open a file from a SharePoint Online location as compared to a local file system.  When you're opening the local path, Windows automatically authenticate you in the background and it "just works".  When you're trying to go after cloud hosted content such as this document in SharePoint Online, you will firstly need to authenticate against M365 and secondly use something like REST, CSOM or Graph APIs to get the file.  If you choose REST (since its the future anyway), Sunil wrote a great article about accessing SharePoint REST calls using OAuth here:
https://www.advaiya.com/access-sharepoint-rest-api-using-oauth/

The SharePoint REST APIs are documented here by Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

Lastly, if your taste prefers Graph (which to be fair is just an API wrapper for REST calls anyway), then Microsoft has documented that for you here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0